# failed when calling luaT_pushudata for the second time in a loop

Tags: c++, api, lua

I am using lua's c api and had some trouble.

When I am doing some loops, luaT_pushudata always fails when I called it **for the second time** and said that
 '**no source available for lua_newuserdata() at 0x7ffff7ba85b3**'
(when debugging in eclipse)

And when directly running the excusable, it just said '
**segmentation fault (core dumped)** 
here is part of my codes (they are within a loop):

```cpp
// establish the new tuple
tupleA temptupleA;
// cannot delete the buffer_char, the buffer char must be deallocate manually when erase the vector
unsigned char * buffer_char = new unsigned char[rect.width*rect.height*3];
glReadPixels(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer_char);
temptupleA.pic = buffer_char;
temptupleA.action = new double[3];
temptupleA.reward = new double[1];
totalBuffer.push_back(temptupleA);

// set action
// get the Action

double * buffer = charA2fA(totalBuffer[totalStep].pic, raw_width*raw_height*3);
//std::cout<<buffer[raw_width*raw_height*3-1]<<std::endl;// check
THDoubleStorage *mystorage0 =  THDoubleStorage_newWithData(&buffer[0], raw_width*raw_height*3);
THDoubleTensor* mytensor0 = THDoubleTensor_newWithStorage4d(
                    mystorage0, 0,
                    1, raw_width*raw_height*3,
                    3, raw_width*raw_height,
                    raw_width, raw_height,
                    raw_height, raw_width);
lua_getglobal(L, "returnAction");

std::cout<<totalStep; //check
luaT_pushudata(L, (void *)mytensor0, "torch.DoubleTensor"); // there is something wrong
std::cout<<" pass the luaT_pushudata"<<std::endl;

if(lua_pcall(L,1,3,0)) lua_error(L);
d->ctrl[0] = lua_tonumber(L,-3);
d->ctrl[1] = lua_tonumber(L,-2);
d->ctrl[2] = lua_tonumber(L,-1);
totalBuffer[totalStep].action[0]=d->ctrl[0];
totalBuffer[totalStep].action[1]=d->ctrl[1];
totalBuffer[totalStep].action[2]=d->ctrl[2];
lua_remove(L, -1);
lua_remove(L, -2);
lua_remove(L, -3);

THDoubleTensor_free(mytensor0);
delete [] buffer;
```

So what may be the cause of the problem??

Comment: The "no source available for lua_newuserdata()" message is normal; it means that the Lua library you are using was not compiled with debug symbols, so you won't be able to view the lines of code in it. I don't think you're supposed to free a tensor that is referenced by a userdata.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I did not need the data in the memory allocated by lua api so I have to free it. And I have found the problem: instead of writing `lua_remove(L, -1), lua_remove(L, -2), lua_remove(L, -3)`  I should simply write `lua_pop(L, 3)` or write `lua_remove(L, -1)` for three times

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem: instead of writing lua_remove(L, -1), lua_remove(L, -2), lua_remove(L, -3) I should simply write lua_pop(L, 3) or write lua_remove(L, -1) for three times

Answer (score 0):

`luaT_pushudata` steals a references, so you might access freed memory. Check with valgrind.